# Cache task in Azure Pipeline to reducer build time

Tags: azure, docker, npm, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I would like to use Azure Pipeline "Cache Task" to cache npm and later on when I build my docker image based on dockerfile, use that cache to decrease my build time. I do rarely, to almost never change my package.json file nowadays, but the docker image build in Azure Pipeline is very slow. If I take a look at the logs while building etc. based on my dockerfile, the command 'npm install' makes up most of the build time. I've made some research but can't find such case...

This is what I've come up with at the moment:

azure-pipeline.yml

```
- "test"
resources:
  - repo: self
pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
variables:
  tag: "$(Build.BuildId)"
  DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
  npm_config_cache: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.npm

steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | package.json'
      path: "$(npm_config_cache)"
      cacheHitVar: "CACHE_RESTORED"
    displayName: Cache npm
  - script: npm ci
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Build an image
    inputs:
      command: "build"
      Dockerfile: "**/Dockerfile.test"
      arguments: "--cache-from=$(npm_config_cache)" <--- I WOULD LIKE TO USE THE CACHE IN THIS TASK
      tags: "$(tag)"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:19-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
ENV REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=test

RUN npm ci --cache $(npm_config_cache) <-- This is not right but I would like to do something like this
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

#Stage 2
FROM nginx:1.23.2-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm -rf *
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

So what I would like to do is the use the cache task in my azure-pipeline in the next step/task of the azure-pipeline where I build my docker image based on the dockerfile provided above. In my Dockerfile I got the line -> `RUN npm ci --cache $(npm_config_cache)` That somehow I would like to reach it, or is that even possible? I can't really figure it out and maybe I'm totaly wrong about my approach?

Many thanks!